# Looking to arrive at a usable solution for password salting in a PHP/MySQL application?

Tags: php, passwords, hash, salt

After reading about password hashing/salting for an entire day (no lie!), I'm in need of arriving at a solution that works, can be used consistently, and is about secure **enough** for a variety of different sites/applications that are using a shared codebase.

So, here's an idea of a MySQL user table:

```
users { id, username, password_hash, password_salt }
```

..and pseudo-ish code:

```
$s_algo       = 'sha1';
$i_iterations = 1000;
$s_password   = 'mypw123xyuACE&.!3';
$s_salt       = hash($s_algo,uniqid(mt_rand(),true));
$s_result     = $s_password;
for ($i       = 0; $i < $i_iterations; $i++) {
    $s_result    = hash($s_algo,$s_result . $s_salt);
}

echo 'Password: ' . $s_password . "\n";
echo 'Algorithm: ' . $s_algo . "\n";
echo 'Iterations Completed: ' . $i . "\n";
echo 'Salt  : ' . $s_salt . "\n";
echo 'Result: ' . $s_result . "\n";
echo 'Length: (Salt:) ' . strlen($s_salt) . ' (Result:) ' . strlen($s_result) . "\n";
```

The interaction (SQL) between PHP and MySQL is taken as read, as are the bits of PHP code that actually verify the given password from user-land against the stored (salted) hash at authentication time. It's not rocket science. This is from the perspective of already doing all that stuff, but with un-salted hash-only password storage.

From my reading I suspect there could be endless debates about what $s_algo should really be (ok, probably NOT md5), and also $i_iterations. So let's just consider that they are **variables** within this problem scenario, which might change according to the specific context, i.e. storage limitations, server load concerns, etc.

These things aside, is this methodology for creating a per-user-salted passwords in PHP generally sound? Does the 'for' loop need to be in there at all? Is the initial salt creation code ok? Is the salt-length overkill, storage-wise (equal to the eventual hash length). Please people, pick holes (but not too many!)..

Other thoughts:
- What about hash_hmac() - is that a critical improvement over multiple hash() iterations?
- PBKDF2?

Comment: What are you trying to secure?  That can be important in the decision process... are there any password requirements on the site or any other elements of security we should know about?

Comment: Hashing it more than once will just make it take longer to compute hashes, which can be a good thing, but it might be overkill for your application.

Comment: @Webnet trying to cover lots of use-cases with a one-size-fits-all solution. imagine this was being built for a popular framework, or something like WordPress. i.e. everything from simple sites to complex apps and sites. some with more security-critical data in there than others.

Comment: @Brendan ..my question would therefore be: do people actually use just a one-time hash(password + salt) approach in the real world and consider it headache-causing enough to put off hackers in the event of a db breach?

Comment: @Brendan or do i mean hash(hash(password) + salt) ?

Comment: This article has a lot of good information on the topic that I think answer some of your questions: http://www.openwall.com/articles/PHP-Users-Passwords

Comment: @Jonny Nott, I assumed most people just do `hash(password + salt)`, but either way works. I was just commenting that any further hashing after that does nothing except increase the time it takes to calculate the result (which can be helpful for stopping brute force attacks, but like I said, probably overkill).

Answer (score 4):

Sorry, I would've commented on the post but haven't got enough rep yet.

I'd use SHA256 for my hash algo and keep the iterations around 25. Any more than that and it's really overkill. I use a very similar solution for a framework that I've applied to half a dozen sites now. I chose to create an overly complicated random character generator, but I've used it in a lot of other places, including tokenizing financial data.

Another edit: Use a random character generator like this for your salt:

```
function randomChar($length) {
    $characters = array("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "J", "K", "M", "N", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0", "~", "!", "@", "#", "%", "^", "&", "(", ")", ":", "{", "[", "]", "}", "|", "<", ">", ".", ",", "/", "?", "_", "+", "-", "=");
    $charactersNumber = count($characters);
    $charactersNumber--;
    $randomLength = 0;
    while ($randomLength < $length) {
        $currentCharacter = $characters[rand(0,$charactersNumber)];
        if ($currentCharacter == $previousCharacter) {
            $currentCharacter = $characters[rand(0,$charactersNumber)];
        }
        $random .= $currentCharacter;
        $previousCharacter = $currentCharacter;
        $randomLength++;
    }
    return $random;
}
```

Response to iteration question:
If x = hash(password + salt) and from then on x = hash(x + salt)

and 1 evaluation of x takes 10ms, then 2 would take 20 and so on.
So...
25 evaluations = 250ms
and 1000 = 10,000ms.

While it's not going to take 10ms for each one, even .5ms over 1000 is still half a second.

If you only accepted alphanumeric passwords, and a password was 8 characters long, each iteration would add 62^8 (if they hadn't yet found the password) more hashes because they would have to do another has for every single combination they tried.

Comment: In response to the comments again... hashing the password then hashing the result with a salt is pointless (in most cases), you're just increasing that likelihood that you'll trip yourself up along the way.

Comment: @Alex Uhuh, you're speaking my language ;) BTW, in which case **would** a double-salted-hash be needed?

Comment: @Alex which bit of your above comment did you just remove? I remember it being good, no? :)

Comment: Wrote that wrong :) I meant that in most cases you're just tripping yourself up. If you take a step back and look at the iteration solution, the "hash(password)" is kind of like a step 0 that you could feed into the iterator with very little penalty, and very little to gain from it. It's your choice. Don't forget that unless an attacker has both your code and the database table, they don't know how many iterations to run, or even how to salt it. Obviously, hash(salt + pass) and hash(pass + salt) are two different results ;)

Comment: Haha I was a bit rude, so I took it out.

Comment: @Alex if you're dropping iterations from 1000 to 25, why not just drop  to **zero** re-iterations altogether? Isn't the computational cost of 25 iterations going to be equally negligible to the hacker as it is to my script? Or does each of just a few iterations have a significant brute-force-preventing effect?

Comment: I'm gonna post my answer to that as an edit to my post (it's gonna have math!) :)

Comment: Haha ended up using less math than I thought I would.

Comment: You could always just come up with 25 different salts ;)

Comment: @Brendan I'm using per-user salts. What I could do is apply each salt between 1 and 25 times (at random), but then I'd have to store that re-application count integer alongside each user's salt..

Comment: @Johnny Nott, I was joking because salting multiple times is pointless.

Comment: @Brendan I think Alex's suggestion is hashing multiple times is a good idea, because unless the attacker has your code as well as you're db, they cannot know *how many* times you've iterated the salting process, therefore they can never derive passwords using rainbow tables, even if there are per-user salts in the db. I suppose the same would be true if an extra bit of salt found only the code was also added in ???

Comment: My further thoughts on this: Even if I use a per-user SHA-512 salt to create a SHA-512 password hash, and stored both those strings together in the database for each user .. if the db is compromised, it would still be quite straightforward for an attacker to make lookup/rainbow tables to crack *specific individual passwords* if they wanted to. BUT, if there's something additional in the code (salting iterations, or an extra global salt string) then this looking up becomes impossible unless the code is also compromised, n'est pas?

Comment: ...So my question would be: is there any value in the db-only per-user salting approach over, say, just hashing the raw password? Does it just make it marginally harder to crack the passwords??

Comment: @Jonny Nott: Rainbow tables aren't used to crack a single password, that would be a waste of space. The point of a rainbow table is to crack a lot of passwords at the same time. The reason salt is useful is that every bit in the salt makes a rainbow table twice as big, so even a small salt makes them infeasible. For example, using a 32-bit salt 4,294,967,296 times bigger. I found some rainbow tables here: http://rainbowtables.shmoo.com/ The alpha-numeric one is 1.2 GB, and doesn't work with salts. To make that same rainbow table with 32-bit salt would take 4.8 Exabytes.

Comment: Your idea of having a salt that's not in the database sounds good to me, since it could protect you if just the database is compromised.

Comment: @Alex Miller: Instead of a random character generator, I find it easier to just use `rand()` and store the salt as an int in the database, and then still do `hash($password + (string)$salt)` (the cast because password could be an integer and that would get confusing). It's faster and should take up less space.

Comment: is re-hashing with the salt an unknown number of iterations just as effective as a code-based hidden extra salt string?

Comment: @Jonny Nott: Using a non-database salt is more effective and cheaper (in terms of processing power). The problem with a random number of hashing iterations is that you have to use a small number (because you don't want a huge pause every time you need to check a password). So the attacker could just try hashing 1-100 times. Each time, they already have the previous hash, so they can just keep doing. This would make breaking each password up to 100x slower, but in that case you might as well hash 100x always, since the fact that it's unknown doesn't help at all.

Comment: @Jonny Nott: On the other hand, the length of your salt is much harder to guess. It could be several KB if you wanted while still causing less of a slow-down than just hashing a couple times. Also, the salt's effectiveness increases exponentially (while hashing multiple times increases linearly). Even a 32-bit unknown salt increases the time to break a password by a factor of 4 billion. A 64-bit unknown salt increases it by a factor of 10^19 (the difference between breaking a password in a second and 100 billion years). And that's still trivial to store. You might as well use a 512 bit one ;)

Comment: And that's not even discussing collisions (if you're using a bigger salt than your hash, there are guaranteed collisions, so they can't even be sure that they got the right password/salt combination).

Answer (score 1):

I read an article yesterday in response to one of my questions on security here: http://chargen.matasano.com/chargen/2007/9/7/enough-with-the-rainbow-tables-what-you-need-to-know-about-s.html

It specifically says that the faster the encryption is the worst it is and it listed MD5 and SHA1 as some of the worst. Although they are microseconds apart, that converts to very long times in making a rainbow table.

I read in php manuals this: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php#89574 where the guy ran a test of each algo and came up with speeds of each one. And based on my readings and that I use RipeMD with a 50 character salt.
On the things you were asking:
 The thing is you are generating a random salt and then storing it in the database which seems unnecessarily redundant. I'd personally rather have one salt hidden in my php code rather then many unique salts nested in a database. Plus why are you hashing the salt?

Comment: Good Qs. Er, I understood that a longer salt = more entropy, so hashing the salt (in the case of sha1) gives 40 chars salt = good?

Comment: Yeah, I read that same article (and about 1,000,000 others!). I guess it depends on whether one thinks an attacker would go to the trouble of creating rainbow tables for each of your salts **anyway**, as opposed to the finer details of how much resources/time that might require..

Comment: I've read lots in favour of one-salt-per-password. I'm coming from the standpoint of a full server breach I guess, code, db, the lot. With a one-time salt in PHP code, once the attacker has that, your passwords may as well have been hash-only MD5s, no? Rainbow Table-arama!

Comment: Well then you can just come up with a 40 char salt. I mean its nit picky but its just means that every time you want to create/store/use a password you have to run one more line of code... PLUS (just came to my mind) if you dont pre-hash your salt you aren't limiting the salt to lower case alpha numerics... with a random salt you can have something like 5Ad%@$(dklfje but when you has it before it becomes "924f19cf7bda3e746ab0174bc2fd3d9ced5b8d70" << actual conversion of that.

Comment: heres a quick function I found online function generate_code($p_length) {
$char_list = "ABCDEFGHJKMNPQRSTUVWXY";
$char_list .= "3456789";
$random = "";
srand((double) microtime() * 1000000);
for($i = 0; $i < $p_length; $i++) {
$random .= substr($char_list, (rand() % (strlen($char_list))), 1);
}
return $random;
}// function generate_code

Comment: change the charlist to include lower case letters as well as symbols and do a simple $salt = generate_code(40);

Comment: NC: Like Jonny said, using a single salt across all passwords is a bad idea. But, as you said using a random character generator is a very *good* idea. Adding ~!@#$%^&*()_+`-= to the salt would do wonders.

Comment: Yeah Alex you are right, for extreme security applications using the same salt wouldnt be a good idea but still rainbow tables are not an overnight endeavor. But what I see as overkill... some see as minimum.

Comment: Think I prefer the hash method = keeps the code for the PHP interpreter to crunch through lighter? All the hashing algorithms are in compiled C code internally, and we're hearing lots about how FAST they all are ;) (sic)

Comment: You don't have to worry about a performance hit when you're only generating the salt when a user's password is created/changed. Once you're just retrieving it form MySQL, don't even worry about it.

Comment: Do as you will. The ultimate security precaution would be add more character options into salt (although still its overkill but IMO unique salting is overkill too). As for speed, it totally depends on your application but usually speed shouldn't be an issue. For most internet applications that difference in the generation between the generate_code function and the hash generator would arbitrary.